# Laravel equivalent division

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner Laravel developer. I use in my project Laravel 8.

I have migration:

```
Schema::create('selected_product_ingredients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('ingredient_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('group_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('single_product_analysis_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->boolean('type')->default(false);
            $table->decimal('weight', 12, 3)->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('laboratoryingredients')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and controller:

```
$itemsAll = $this->selectedProductIngredient->with(['item'])
            ->select('product_id', 'ingredient_id')
            ->selectRaw('sum(weight) as weight_sum')
            ->where('single_product_analysis_id', 0)
            ->where('group_id', $id)
            ->where('type', 2)
            ->groupBy('ingredient_id')
            ->orderByDesc('weight_sum')
            ->get();

dd($itemsAll)


Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1969 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => App\Models\SelectedProductIngredient {#1975 ▼
      #fillable: array:6 [▶]
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #dates: array:2 [▶]
      #casts: array:2 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "selected_product_ingredients"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "product_id" => 18
        "ingredient_id" => 4
        "weight_sum" => "224.000"
      ]
```

It's work fine.

I need to make one change. In the weight_sum field, I need to divide the weight_sum by the number of summarized records (weight_sum / quantity).

So we currently have:

- weight = 1
- weight = 2
- weight = 3

weight_sum = 6

I would like to get w weight_sum = 6: 3 (3 records) = 2

How can I do this?

Please help

Comment: Something like this: `->selectRaw('sum(weight) / COUNT(weight) as weight_sum')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```
class ProductIngredient extends Model
{
    public function getAverageWeight()
    {
        return $this->item->avg('weight');
        // same as: $this->item->sum('weight') / $this->item->count();
    }
}
```

Or you can add another [relation aggregation function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) to the query:

```
$itemsAll = $this->selectedProductIngredient->with(['item'])->withAvg('item', 'weight')
            ->select('product_id', 'ingredient_id')
            ->selectRaw('sum(weight) as weight_sum')
            ->where('single_product_analysis_id', 0)
            ->where('group_id', $id)
            ->where('type', 2)
            ->groupBy('ingredient_id')
            ->orderByDesc('weight_sum')
            ->get();
```